# How to Navigate to Contact Creation Page

Tags: visualforce, record-type, standardcontroller, redirect, button-overrides

My use case is that I have overridden the 'View' button with a Visualforce page which immediately redirects to either a Visualforce page or the standard detail page based on the RecordType. I would like to extend this functionality to the 'New' button so that after the record type is selected, I navigate appropriately.

However, I have been unable to find a method that generates the page for a new record. Using edit() on the standardController throws an error. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried returning a `PageReference` to `/003/e`? That's the page that you get to create a new contact.

Try this:

**Visualforce:**

```
<apex:page controller="NewContactController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!NewContact}" value="New Contact"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller:**

```
public with sharing class NewContactController {
    public pageReference NewContact()
    {
        return new PageReference ('/003/e?RecordType=<your record type ID>');
    }
}
```

This will take you to the contact creation page whenever you click the 'New Contact' button.

If what you want is to specify a specific record type it might be doable via the queryString... would have to investigate a bit more.

Comment: That seems to have the same effect as pressing the button, causing a redirect loop. Additionally, we do need to specify a record type.

Comment: In order to specify a record type, all you need to do is add the following to the query string: `?RecordType=<your record type ID>`